# Customising git log

Tags: git

I currently have the following alias for a specific `git log` command:

```
alias.lol=log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all
```

This produces an output similar to this:

```
* 248f98d (origin/tg-kvo) standalone recording stuff
* c8db387 test adding standalone with observers
* 348a48c standalone rlmarray kvo
* fdf2981 use normal kvo for standalone objects
* 5085dd1 test standalone
* 95a2724 test
* 88e799b stuff
* b6d8653 fallback for ignored properties
* eaf93f6 add ignored property test
* b35b73f throw on invalid removeObserver
* 9bd9701 array change info
* 0759a01 delay willchange
* e783be5 array change info
* 8455d7f Array modification tests
* a6809ff Set NSKeyValueChangeKindKey
* 3b8d90f minimal array property notifications
* 8032d9b fix tests
* 7902b0f stuff
* 718c434 kvo
* c32e8df perf
```

Which is very close to what I want. However, the perfect output would be:

```
* <abbrev commit> <authors email> <date, either short or relative> <as much of the commit as you can fit in the remaining space>
```

I tried, but the pretty=online interferes with displaying the author and date.

Is there anyway to get this output?

Thanks!

Comment: Side note: `--pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit` can be condensed to `--oneline`. Have you had a look at the *Pretty formats* section of the [`git-log` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)? You can use `--pretty` to specify a custom format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To format the git log output you can use --pretty option.
Try this:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h%x09%ae %x09%ad%x09%s" --date=short
```